# Probability example A tosses coin B rolls a die

Tags: probability

I have been given this example:

A those a coin and THEN B rolls a Die.
This is repeated independently until a head or one of the numbers 1,2,3,4 appears which the at this time the game is stopped. Note that winning is when the game is stopped and its a fair coin and dice

Compute the probability of of A winning the game.

I see this as follows:

A can win either by getting head on the first or by $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2}(P(5or6|tail)^n = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{2}{12}\right)^n=1/10 $$
(using geometric series)

As these events are mutually exclusive I could sum them up and I get the probability of A given by P(A) is 1/2+1/10=60% chance of A winning.

Now this is the same answer as the book is giving, but in the example they have provided is this solution, which I don't follow:

Using independency, the probability of A wins is thus the conditional probability equals
$$(1/2)/((1/2)+(1/2)*(4/6))$$

Now could someone please show me how these numbers came about?

Comment: @Ross Millikan 
They roll in succession I believe starting with coin

Comment: @RossMillikan I am very sure to be honest, I actually didn't write it properly cause it does state: Person A tosses a coin and THEN person B rolls a die

Comment: @RossMillikan See update

Comment: Then I accomplished what I hoped to.  I have deleted my earlier comments.  It is important to make the question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that after a tail and a $5$ or $6$ we are in the same situation as the start of the game.  That essentially sums the geometric series for you.  If $a$ is the probability that $A$ wins, we have $a=\frac 12 + \frac 12 \cdot \frac 13 a$ because $A$ wins with a head, which is the $\frac 12$ or with a tail and a $5,6$ plus winning the game starting from there.

Comment: The $\frac 12 + \frac 12 \cdot \frac 46$ is the chance the game terminates in one round.  $A$ wins $\frac 12$ of that.  $A$ therefore wins this fraction of the chance the game terminates in each round.  As it terminates with probability $1$, that is the chance $A$ wins.

Comment: how come if A is winning 1/2 of the chance the game is terminated in one round, are they dividing (1/2) with this fraction and not multiplying?

Comment: In one round, $A$ wins $\frac 12$, $B$ wins $\frac 13$, and we replay $\frac 16$.  Assuming we quit now, the chance $A$ won is $\dfrac {\frac 12}{\frac 56}$.  Assuming we quit in the second round, the chance $A$ won is the same.  And the third....

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is using **odds** in its true meaning. Note that if neither wins in the first round,  we are back to square $1$

$P(A \,wins\, in\, round\, 1) = \frac 12,\;\;\; P(B\, wins\, in\, round\, 1) = \frac12\cdot\frac46 $

Odds of $A$ winning $ = \frac12 : \frac12\cdot\frac46 $

so $P(A\, wins) = \dfrac{\frac12}{\frac12 + \frac12\cdot\frac46}$